# https configuration camel-config.xml

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using camel-servlet-no-spring application that is working fine in http protocol. how to i make 'to' as https.

My **camel-config.xml**

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
   <route>
     <from uri="servlet:///service?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
    <loadBalance>
     <failover>
       <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
      </failover>
      <to uri="http://localhost:8082/cdc/services?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
   </loadBalance> 
  </route>
</routes>
```

i want

```
<to uri="https://localhost:8082/cdc/services?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
   <route>
     <from uri="servlet:///service?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
    <loadBalance>
     <failover>
       <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
      </failover>
      <to uri="https://localhost:8082/cdc/services?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
   </loadBalance> 
  </route>
</routes>
```

in uri

```
https://yourhost:8082/
```

i think port number may 443. like

```
https://yourhost:443/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just update the to uri as you want. I don't know what kind of issue did you hit.